# Why would Tensorflow Serving run a model slower than Tensorflow on a Keras stock model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving, nvidia-docker

I've been attempting to deploy a machine learning solution with Tensorflow Serving on an embedded device (Jetson Xavier [ARMv8])

One model used by the solution is a stock Xception network, generated by:

```
xception = tf.keras.applications.Xception(include_top=False, input_shape=(299, 299, 3), pooling=None
xception.save("./saved_xception_model/1", save_format="tf")
```

Running the Xception model on the device generates reasonable performance - about 0.1s to predict, ignoring all processioning:

```
xception = tf.keras.models.load_model("saved_xception_model/1", save_format="tf")
image = get_some_image() # image is numpy.ndarray
image.astype("float32")
image /= 255
image = cv2.resize(image, (299, 299))
# Tensorflow predict takes ~0.1s
xception.predict([image])
```

However, once the model is running in a Tensorflow Serving GPU container, via Nvidia-Docker, the model is much slower - about 3s to predict.

I've been trying to isolate the cause of the poor performance, and I've run out of ideas.

So far I've tested:

1. Tweaking TF Serving's batching parameters to go all out on latency
   (`batch_timeout_micros: 0`, `max_batch_size: 1`, and noticed a
   modest 0.5s gain in performance.
2. Optimizing the model with TensorRT via `saved_model_cli`.
3. Running the Xception model in isolation, as the only model being served by TF Serving.
4. Experimenting with doubling the memory allocated per TF process.
5. Experimenting with enabling and disabling batching altogether.
6. Experimenting with enabling and disabling model warmup.

I would expect TF Serving to provide the same (more or less, allowing for GRPC encoding and decoding) prediction time as TF, and they do for other models I'm running. None of my efforts have got Xception upto the ~0.1s performance I would expect.

My install of Tensorflow is built by Nvidia, from TF version 2.0.
My TF Serving container is self-built from the TF-Serving 2.0 source, with GPU support.

I start a Tensorflow Serving container as follows:

```
tf_serving_cmd = "docker run --runtime=nvidia -d"
tf_serving_cmd += " --name my-container"
tf_serving_cmd += " -p=8500:8500 -p=8501:8501"
tf_serving_cmd += " --mount=type=bind,source=/home/xception_model,target=/models/xception_model"
tf_serving_cmd += " --mount=type=bind,source=/home/model_config.pb,target=/models/model_config.pb"
tf_serving_cmd += " --mount=type=bind,source=/home/batching_config.pb,target=/models/batching_config.pb"

# Self built TF serving image for Jetson Xavier, ARMv8.
tf_serving_cmd += " ${MY_ORG}/serving" 
# I have tried 0.5 with no performance difference. 

# TF-Serving does not complain it wants more memory in either case.
tf_serving_cmd += " --per_process_gpu_memory_fraction:0.25"
tf_serving_cmd += " --model_config_file=/models/model_config.pb"
tf_serving_cmd += " --flush_filesystem_caches=true"
tf_serving_cmd += " --enable_model_warmup=true"
tf_serving_cmd += " --enable_batching=true"
tf_serving_cmd += " --batching_parameters_file=/models/batching_config.pb"
```

I'm at the point where I'm starting to wonder if this is a bug in TF-Serving, although I have no idea where (Yeah, I know it's never a bug, it's always the user...)

Can anyone suggest why TF-Serving might underperform compared to TF?

Comment: I know this is not an answer but can you pls share your Dockerfile (to create the TF Serving container)? I'm for now unable to even get that working on a tx2 but will work on the same perf problem, likely, afterward.

Comment: @omartin2010 Unfortunately our Dockerfiles are propitiatory so I'm not at liberty to share them. You'll need to compile a Bazel container first, base your image on the Linux for Tegra container, invoke `nvidia-docker build...` to expose the host libraries, hack all the missing headers and libraries from the build into `/etc/nvidia-container-runtime/host-files-for-dontainer.d/` (trial and error, one at a time...), juggle your swapfile size, and Bazel build resources to avoid out-of-memory problems, then adjust all the missing and unneded Dockerfile apt and pip dependencies. Trial and error.. :/

Comment: @omartin2010 Took us two weeks, and 1,000 lines of shell script. I'm sorry I can't help you more. Edit: oh yeah, you'll also have to change all the CUDA and TensorRT variables to match whatever versions are installed on your host.

Comment: For now I'm instead building my own tf serving thing, basically a flask app. My case isn't particularly important to justify really having tf serving there but thanks for the answer anyways, it might help if I pursue that route!

Comment: As mentioned above by @omartin2010 its hard to debug this issue as I am unable to reproduce it. If yo find a minimal example, please share it.